# How to fix TypeError [INVALID_TYPE]: Supplied parameter is not a User nor a Role

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm running into a problem when I'm trying to create a role and a text channel. The role created will set permissions for the text channel.

```js
if (id === '4') {
  message.guild.roles.create({
    name: `Owner`,
    color: `${color.white}`,
    permissions: ['ADD_REACTIONS'],
    hoist: true,
  });

  let owner = message.guild.roles.cache.find((role) => role.name === 'Owner');

  name = `${names.name}`,
    message.guild.channels
      .create(name, {
        type: 'GUILD_TEXT',
        permissionOverwrites: [
          {
            id: owner,
            allow: ['ADD_REACTIONS'],
            deny: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'],
          },
        ],
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
}
```

Although it creates the role, when it comes to the text channel, it cannot find the role made and throws an error:

```
TypeError [INVALID_TYPE]: Supplied parameter is not a User nor a Role.
```

I'm unsure how to fix this.

Comment: Seems `owner` is `undefined`. Try logging `owner`

Comment: @MrMythical Yeah it undefined.

Comment: Make sure the role exists. Also make sure it's cached, run `message.guild.roles.fetch()`

Comment: From what I saw from a few tests was that when "Owner" role is already added to the server its fine and it works. But it there is no "Owner" role it will come back undefined and will not create a text channel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`roles.create()` is an asynchronous method, which means it returns a promise and allows the rest of your code to run without blocking anything. It also means that when you try to find the newly created role on the next line, it won't be there as it's not even created, so it will be `undefined`. As `undefined` is not a valid `Role` or `User`, you receive a `TypeError`.

However, [`roles.create()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/RoleManager?scrollTo=create) resolves to the newly created role, so you can wait for it to be created (using `await` for example) and grab its value. This way you don't even need to find it later. Check out the code below:

```js
let owner = await message.guild.roles.create({
  name: `Owner`,
  color: color.white,
  permissions: ['ADD_REACTIONS'],
  hoist: true,
});

message.guild.channels
  .create(names.name, {
    type: 'GUILD_TEXT',
    permissionOverwrites: [
      {
        // now owner is a valid role
        id: owner,
        allow: ['ADD_REACTIONS'],
        deny: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'],
      },
    ],
  })
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you haven't awaited the role create a function.
Try using this code:

```
 if(id === '4'){


        await message.guild.roles.create({
            name: `Owner`,
            color: `${color.white}`,
            permissions: ["ADD_REACTIONS"],
            hoist: true
        });


        let owner = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Owner");

        name = `${names.name}`,
        await message.guild.channels.create(name, {
            type: "GUILD_TEXT",  
            permissionOverwrites: [{
                id: owner,
                allow: ['ADD_REACTIONS'],
                deny: ['VIEW_CHANNEL']
            }]
        }).catch(err => console.log(err));

    }
```